# Go text/template templates: how to build a fallback when parent node in JSON input doesn't exist?

Tags: json, go, if-statement, templates

Let's say you have a JSON input that normally comes into your system, like:

`{ "foods": { "plants": { "fruit": "apple" } } }`

But you want to be able to handle a case where the "plants" node doesn't exist or its value is null. Like:

`{ "foods": { "plants": null } }`

or

`{ "foods": { "fungi": { "mushrooms": "button" } } }`.

When I've tried doing various if statements and things (like `{{ if .foods.plants.fruits }}stuff...{{ end }}`, I keep running into errors like `<.foods.plants.fruits>: map has no entry for key "plants"` or `<.foods.plants.fruits>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.fruits`

I want a template where, if the parent node does not exist, I can try checking a fallback option, without the Go panicking or the template refusing to continue executing. Like, say, have it use `foods.fungi.mushrooms` alternate node if the `plants` parent node doesn't exist.

Is this possible in Go text/templates? I scoured through the docs and did some googling but am not seeing anything obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A coworker of mine suggested a solution that ended up working: use the built-in `index` function:

`{{ if index .foods "plants" }}do stuff{{ else }}do other stuff when '.foods.plants' is missing{{ end }}`